# Raspberry PI wont receive broadcast from Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to make a simple "device discovery" app with a PC and a Raspberry Pi. I am using Qt to do this.

Heres the idea...

I have a Qt Application that runs on my PC, I hit a "Search" button to broadcast a UDP packet with a "Request" message as the datagram. Here is the basic UDP.cpp class (im not including the GUI itself).

```
    MyUDP::MyUDP(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "Binding UDP Socket";
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 5000); //bind to 5000
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void MyUDP::deviceDiscover(){
    QByteArray data;
    data.append("Request");
    qDebug() << "Sending broadcast";
    socket->writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress::Broadcast, 5000); //broadcast from port 5000
}

void MyUDP::readyRead(){
    QByteArray buffer;
    buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    //var to store headers from udp
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 sender_port;
    socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(),buffer.size(), &sender, &sender_port);
    qDebug() << "Message from " << sender << " port " << sender_port;
    qDebug() << "Msg: " << buffer;
    if(QString(buffer).compare("PI")==0){
        //add to list
        emit(updateList(sender.toString()));
    }

}
```

Now on the PI I have a simple console application that is suppose to read broadcast packets and just echo back a "PI" msg.

Here is the PI Code

```
MyUDP::MyUDP(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "Binding UDP Socket";
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 5000); //bind to 5000
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readyRead()));
    qDebug() << "Ready Read signal connected,sending out broadcast";
    QByteArray data;
    data.append("PI");
    qDebug() << "Sending datagram";
    socket->writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress::Broadcast, 5000); //broadcast from port 5000
}

void MyUDP::readyRead(){
    QByteArray buffer;
    buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    //var to store headers from udp
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 sender_port;
    socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(),buffer.size(), &sender, &sender_port);
    qDebug() << "Message from " << sender << " port " << sender_port;
    qDebug() << "Msg: " << buffer;
    if(QString(buffer).compare("Request")==0){
        //send back a "PI" msg
        QByteArray data;
        data.append("PI");
        socket->writeDatagram(data, sender, 5000);
    }
}
```

Now When the PI code first runs, it broadcasts an "alive" msg and the PC app gets it no problem.

Here is my start up sequence (starting the PI app while PC is already running)

```
Message from   QHostAddress( "192.168.211.1" )   port  5000 
Msg:  "Request" 
Message from   QHostAddress( "192.168.1.111" )   port  5000 
Msg:  "PI" 
Updating list
```

Now when I use the search button to send a broadcast, the PI side does not receive anything.

I flushed all the rules for iptables and turned off my windows firewall. Any ideas on what would be preventing the PI from receiving broadcasts from windows?

If I run windows-windows, both receive "request" messages when searching.

Comment: ** Found the solution, my VM created a bunch of interface ports that was screwing it up. Works now :).

Comment: Not all consumer switches support broadcast well.